# Multifilter Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I'm trying to create a filter for some content.
However I'm not sure how to solve this problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOPPaB

html

```
<span class="toggle" id="red">Toggle red</span>
<span class="toggle" id="blue">Toggle blue</span>
<span class="toggle" id="big">Toggle Big</span>
<span class="toggle" id="small">Toggle Small</span>
<div id="content" class="red small"></div>
<div id="content" class="red big"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue small"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue big"></div>
```

js

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("." + id).toggle();
});
```

It works fine when i just try to toggle the size or the color individually.
But if I try to mix them up it does not work as intended.

If I click "toggle red" and "toggle small" it should only show the big blue ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the way [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) should work.
Once you click on `red` for example - the first and second divs are hidden and 3rd and 4rd are shown:

```
<div id="content" class="red small" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="content" class="red big" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue small"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue big"></div>
```

Then, if you click on `big` - each element with the `big` class will get toggled, so if `red big` had the `display: none;`, now it will be `display: block`, and the `blue big` will now have `display: none`, so your result will be:

```
<div id="content" class="red small" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="content" class="red big" style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue small"></div>
<div id="content" class="blue big" style="display: none;"></div>
```

To make sure you have a "multi-filter" you might wanna add to your buttons the information that it was toggled, and then toggle (or show/hide) only the elements that related to all of your filteres.

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
    toggledIds = []
    $('.toggled').each(function(i, e){
        toggledIds[toggledIds.length] = $(e).attr('id')
    });
    // Now you can do whatever you want with the list of the ids
});
```

If you click on `red`, then on `big` and then on `blue`, you will get `toggledIds == ['red', 'big', 'blue']`